# Swift - Function in other view controller is not being called (protocol / delegate)

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, protocols

I'm trying to call the function `updateProgress` from a `LoadingDataHelper` object but my delegate is not being called. I think the problem is that this `LoadingDataHelper` is not connected to the `LoadingDataViewController` (I mean like when you're having a `UIView` and a `viewController`).

**LoadingDataHelper**

```
protocol LoadingNewDataDelegate: class {
    func updateProgress(progress : Float)
}

class LoadingDataHelper: NSObject {
    var delegate: LoadingNewDataDelegate?
    static let shared = LoadingDataHelper() // shared instance

    func loginUser() {
    //more code
        updateProgressInViewController()
    //more code
    }

    func updateProgressInViewController() {
        delegate?.updateProgress(0.3)
    }

}
```

**LoadingDataViewController**

```
class LoadingDataViewController: UIViewController, LoadingNewDataDelegate {

let loadingDataHelper: LoadingDataHelper = LoadingDataHelper()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        loadingDataHelper.delegate = self
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        if (NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("approvedTermsOfUse")) {
            self.updateProgress(0.1)
            LoadingDataHelper.shared.loginUser()
        } else {
            self.askForTerms()
        }
    }

    func updateProgress(progress : Float) {
        self.progressBar.setProgress(progress, animated: true)
        self.progressBar.setNeedsDisplay()
    }
}
```

Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: Where do you call `updateProgressInViewController`?

Comment: also, you'd better make one of references `var delegate` or `let loadingDataHelper` weak in order to prevent reference cycle.

Comment: Please add that code to your question.

Comment: Is this your actual code? You have a typo - extra `func` in front of `updateProgressInViewController()` when you are trying to call the method

Comment: @Phillip: It's called by another function in LoadingDataHelper: loginUser(). And loginUser is called by LoadingDataViewController. I added the code to my question. Thanks! @: dmorrow: that was a small mistake when adding the question. In my real code, the typo is not there.

Comment: `let loadingDataHelper: LoadingDataHelper = LoadingDataHelper()` `static let shared = LoadingDataHelper()` is that the same object?

Comment: As @Larme suggests, the object you use when setting the delegate is not the same object you use when calling `loginUser()`.

Comment: @Larme: That was it! I changed loadingDataHelper.delegate = self to -->  LoadingDataHelper.shared.delegate = self. And now it works! Thank you very much!!!!

Comment: One way to spot it by yourself (if you have this kind of issue in the future): check before `delegate?.updateProgress(0.3)`, if `delegate` is nil. If it is, and you are pretty sure you set it (`yourObject.delegate = something`), check the address of your object (In `LoadingDataHelper` it's `self`), and the one that owns it (in `LoadingDataViewController`, it's `loadingDataHelper`). You may spot different addresses.

Comment: I will do that, thanks!

Comment: @PhillipMills is it a good practice to make your delegating class a singleton?

Comment: In your question, it's not common to say `UIViewController LoadingDataViewController`it's confusing...simply say `LoadingDataViewController`. See my edit.

Comment: @Honey -- I can't see any reason in the provided code for `LoadingDataHelper` being a singleton at all.  If it **is** a singleton (and therefore can be accessed from any object), having one delegate seems like an invitation to confusion.  If different objects may need to know about progress, notifications sound like a cleaner approach.

Answer (score 0):

There is some wrong in above codeL:
In LoadingDataViewController, you are creating static property for **LoadingDataHelper** class and setting delegate to that class. But you are call "loginUser" using direct call.

You need to change like below:

```
class LoadingDataViewController: UIViewController, LoadingNewDataDelegate {    
**//Change to shared initialisation of object//**
let loadingDataHelper: LoadingDataHelper = LoadingDataHelper.shared

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        loadingDataHelper.delegate = self
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        if (NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("approvedTermsOfUse")) {
            self.updateProgress(0.1)
           **//Call using static object instead of new instance or direct call//**
            loadingDataHelper.loginUser()
        } else {
            self.askForTerms()
        }
    }

    func updateProgress(progress : Float) {
        self.progressBar.setProgress(progress, animated: true)
        self.progressBar.setNeedsDisplay()
    }
}
```

This will make your controller to get delegate call back.